# How can I get the current Box user's information?

Tags: box-api

Is there any way to retrieve the currently logged in Box user's `user` object?

I'm primarily concerned about enterprise admin accounts, where the `/users` endpoint is documented as returning all users. How will I know which of these users is the one that made the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the V2 API, a user can call GET on /users and you will get yourself back.

```
{
    "total_count": 1,
    "entries": [
        {
            "type": "user",
            "id": "13243406",
            "name": "Robert Stark",
            "login": "rstark@winterfell.com",
            "created_at": "2011-08-24T14:00:25-07:00",
            "modified_at": "2012-10-10T04:32:24-07:00",
            "role": "user",
            "language": "en",
            "space_amount": 53687091200,
            "space_used": 48671461,
            "max_upload_size": 104857600,
            "tracking_codes": [],
            "see_managed_users": false,
            "sync_enabled": true,
            "status": "active",
            "job_title": "",
            "phone": "",
            "address": "",
            "avatar_url": "https://api.box.com/api/avatar/large/13243406"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But what happens if the current user is an Enterprise admin? The documentation says that this returns a list of all users in the enterprise; how do I know which user in the list is the calling user? This is something I can't easily test.

Comment: We're going to be adding a convenience endpoint GET /users/me sometime soon... but it is not there yet.

Comment: @dauphic to determine whoami, currently I call /folders/0 to reach for root folder, and get whoami via created_by/owned_by

Answer (score 3):

You can use the /users/me endpoint to get information about the current user.

[get-the-current-users-information](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-the-current-users-information)

```curl
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

```js
200
{
    "type": "user",
    "id": "17738362",
    "name": "sean rose",
    "login": "sean@box.com",
    "created_at": "2012-03-26T15:43:07-07:00",
    "modified_at": "2012-12-12T11:34:29-08:00",
    "language": "en",
    "space_amount": 5368709120,
    "space_used": 2377016,
    "max_upload_size": 262144000,
    "status": "active",
    "job_title": "Employee",
    "phone": "5555555555",
    "address": "555 Office Drive",
    "avatar_url": "https://app.box.com/api/avatar/large/17738362"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Information about the current user is returned in the get_auth_token call that occurs during the Auth process.  See [Step 4 under Authentication](http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating):

```
<response>
  <status>get_auth_token_ok</status>
  <auth_token>yv9usmcmbnfhtx2y8rmlvk1csnoz65oo</auth_token>
  <user>
    <login>joe@example.com</login>
    <email>joe@example.com</email>
    <access_id>31313825</access_id>
    <user_id>31313825</user_id>
    <space_amount>5361200</space_amount>
    <space_used>47477</space_used>
    <max_upload_size>104800</max_upload_size>
    <sharing_disabled/>
  </user>
</response>
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily going through the authentication process; I may be using an auth token that has been stored elsewhere.